# How to solve the expected indentation block error in python using vs code

Tags: python, indentation

I have tried running my code but I keep getting expected indentation errors even when I configured my space settings to 4 but when I debug, it works. I am using vs code, please help

```
for k in range (50):
    print(k)
```